Generate tree from SQL in ksh
This code only shows the first level and the leaves of the first element of that level that is directly connected to the root (the leftmost one).
Could you please tell me what error I am making? Thank you very much in advance.
PRC_SECUENCIA=$1

Inp_OraServicio=IGRI
Inp_OraSep=$SQL_IFS

Inp_OraServicio=IGRI
Inp_OraSep=$SQL_IFS
Inp_OraSql="SELECT SECUENCIA FROM IGRI.BOL_INC_DE_RED WHERE
SEC_BOLETIN_RAIZ='${PRC_SECUENCIA}' 
ORDER BY SECUENCIA"

IFS=$__SL
  set -- ${Out_Comentario}
IFS=${__IFS}

array=${array[@]},${PRC_SECUENCIA}


for __derivado in "${@}"
do

 array=${array[@]},${__derivado}

print -r -- "${__derivado}" >> /users/cairo/OmegaCAIRO/bin/GesOPV2/FunEntAstro/pbaFunciones/arbol.log
FunEnt_OPV_getIgriTicketDerivados_Arbol ${__derivado}

done

Example:
The problem is that it only adds the first level of the tree, and the leftmost branch to the end, like this:
if my tree is: 1 1.1 1.2 1.1.1 1.1.2 1.2.1 1.2.2
I can only visualize : 1 ,1.1, 1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.2
I still need to visualize: 1.2.1 1.2.2

Your question makes no sense without showing some sample data.

What do you expect this to do? array=${array[@]},${PRC_SECUENCIA}

Hello,
for example, if i have this tree :
        1

1.1             1.2
1.1.1  1.1.2     1.2.1  1.2.2
with mi code, with my code, I can only display :
        1

1.1             1.2
1.1.1  1.1.2
with this array=${array[@]},${PRC_SECUENCIA} what i do is accumulate the next element in the array

The way to append an element to an array is array+=( "${PRC_SECUENCIA}" )

the ksh that is mininstalled on my machine does not support doing this array+=( "${PRC_SECUENCIA}" ) that's why I did that way : array=${array[@]},${PRC_SECUENCIA}. The problem is that it only adds the first level of the tree, and the leftmost branch to the end, like this:
if my tree is: 1 1.1 1.2 1.1.1 1.1.2 1.2.1 1.2.2
I can only visualize : 1 ,1.1, 1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.2
I still need to visualize: 1.2.1 1.2.2
thank you anyway!

Not an answer, just providing some formatting for array=${array[@]},${PRC_SECUENCIA} 
$ array=(1 2 3 4 5)
$ PRC_SECUENCIA=6

What does the array look like
$ typeset -p array   # => typeset -a array=(1 2 3 4 5)

Then, "append" to it:
$ array=${array[@]},${PRC_SECUENCIA}
$ typeset -p array   # => typeset -a array=('1 2 3 4 5,6' 2 3 4 5)

You're only altering the first element of the array, and adding a literal comma as well.


the ksh that is mininstalled on my machine does not support doing this array+=( "${PRC_SECUENCIA}" )


what version of ksh do you have? ksh --version
try this way to append:
array=("${array[@]}" "${PRC_SECUENCIA}")



